# записать текущее время

Tags: c

Как получить текущее время и записать его в массив строк? используя данный код, каждый элемент массива будет указывать на одно и то же время, а надо чтобы время отличалось. 1-й элемент 19:44, 2-й элемент -19:45 и т.д.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct tm *ptr;
    time_t lt;

    lt = time(NULL);
    ptr = localtime(&lt);
    printf(asctime(ptr));
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Поясните, как *текущего* времени может быть несколько *отличающихся* значений? И в какой массив нужно эти значения записать, в вашем коде ничего подобного нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include < stdio.h >  // Для printf
#include < time.h >   // Для time, ctime

int main (void)
{    
   // Переменная для сохранения текущего времени
   long int ttime;

   // Считываем текущее время
   ttime = time (NULL);

   // С помощью функции ctime преобразуем считанное время в
   // локальное, а затем в строку и выводим в консоль.
   printf (“Время: %s\n”,ctime (&ttime) );

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Согласно [спецификации](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=asctime&russian=2), функция `asctime()` возвращает указатель на статическую строку, которая перезаписывается при каждом вызове функции. Значит, если нужно сохранять полученные значения, их нужно куда-то копировать. Например, так:

```
struct tm *ptr;
time_t lt;
char *data[2];

lt = time(NULL);
ptr = localtime(&lt);
data[0] = strdup( asctime(ptr) );

sleep(10);

lt = time(NULL);
ptr = localtime(&lt);
data[1] = strdup( asctime(ptr) );

printf( "%s\n%s\n", data[0], data[1] );

free( data[0] );
free( data[1] );
```

В `POSIX` и `BSD` ещё функция `asctime_r()`, которая принимает указатель на строку для сохранения, длина которой должна быть не меньше 26 байт. С учётом этого можно так:

```
struct tm *ptr;
time_t lt;
char data[2][26];

lt = time(NULL);
ptr = localtime(&lt);
asctime_r(ptr, data[0]);

sleep(10);

lt = time(NULL);
ptr = localtime(&lt);
asctime_r(ptr, data[1]);

printf( "%s\n%s\n", data[0], data[1] );
```

То же самое касается и более короткого варианта в ответе @AlexUlianov, есть `ctime()`, а есть и `ctime_r()`.